# Calculating the reactive current supplied to the grid by a generator

Tags: reactive-power

I have a calculation I don't really understand. Can someone help me to understand how this goes?

[image]

I have to calculate that I reactive power.

- G = generator
- M1 =tranformer
- M2 = transformer2
- johto = wire

Comment: Can you say what *exactly* it is you don't understand? Protip: if you show what you tried then people will be able to pinpoint (sometimes with incredible accuracy) where and what you went wrong. Some may even be willing to gove extra tips and hints.

Comment: Try translating into English from Finnish too.

Comment: What have you attempted so far and where are you stuck?

Comment: I dont really know even how to start or what formula i have to use :/

Comment: Propogate the source voltage to the load through the transformers, then propogate the load current to the source.

Answer (score 1):

Convert everything to per-unit.  Then you can calculate the current flow from the generator through the  series circuit to the load bus.

From that you can calculate everything you’re interested in.